# Delphi: TRESTRequest OnHTTPProtocolError event never called

Tags: rest, http, delphi, vcl

I'm using the ExecuteAsync method of a TRESTRequest object, and I've had no luck figuring out how to get the OnHTTPProtocolError event to proc. Instead, I simply get EHTTPProtocolExceptions (500 errors) or timeout exceptions, both being occasions that are supposed to trigger the event, according to the docs.

I've tried assigning compatible methods to both the RESTRequest event and the RESTClient event of the same name, and neither ever procs, I always get an exception. I've also tried a few of the Client properties, like RaiseExceptionOn500 and SynchronizedEvents, but to no avail.

Do I need to use thread execution in a specific way? Directly handling the exception (via managing threads) seems a possible solution, but I'd like to avoid that if possible and see if I can get any answers on why this seemingly straightforward class feature isn't working for me. Thanks.

Edit: Better code sample.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Client: TRESTClient;
    Request: TRESTRequest;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ProtocolErrorTest(Request: TCustomRESTRequest);
    procedure ResponseCall;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Client := TRESTClient.Create('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/status_codes');
  Request.Client := Client;
  Request.Method := rmGET;
  Request.Accept:= 'application/json';

  Request.OnHTTPProtocolError := ProtocolErrorTest;

  Request.Resource := '500';
  Request.ExecuteAsync(ResponseCall);
end;

procedure TForm1.ProtocolErrorTest(Request: TCustomRESTRequest);
begin
  ShowMessage('Got it');
end;

procedure TForm1.ResponseCall;
begin
  ShowMessage('No way');
end;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your example is nowhere complete enough to discover what the problem is

Comment: Thanks Dave, you're right. I'll create a functionally complete sample and edit the question.

Comment: This is just another in a long list of reasons why I DO NOT use Embarcadero's REST framework.  It is very complex and buggy.  I use Indy's `TIdHTTP` instead. For asynchronous work, simply call it in a separate thread via `TThread` or `TTask`.

Comment: Edited with a simpler example. Still the same results. Thanks for the advice Remy, I'll try that.